# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' docker container for dotnet 3.1

Tags: docker, debian, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to deploy an console application.
When I run the container , I get below error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libkernel32.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at Interop.Kernel32.GlobalMemoryStatusEx(MEMORYSTATUSEX& lpBuffer)
at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryMonitor..cctor()
```

Below is code of the docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1

RUN mkdir -p /dest 
ADD /Publish /dest/ 
WORKDIR /dest 

CMD ["dotnet","application.dll"]
```

Any suggestion will be really helpful.